# git opens a file with empty buffer in VS Code using WSL

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu installed for WSL and I am working with it to do my programming stuff.
Visual Studio Code is installed in the Windows system.

The problem is that whenever git needs to open a file in it's core editor (Visual Studio Code in my case), it opens a file in my editor, but it has an empty buffer though.

I've set VS Code as core editor using this command :

```
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

When it opens a file, using `git commit` for instance, I get this :
[empty file in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7xcj.png)

I am pretty sure it is caused by the WSL because I have never had this problem before using other alternative but I can't figure why.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your VS Code is a Windows program and you're running in WSL.

When Git in WSL invokes the editor to edit something like a commit message, it passes a path to the file to edit.  This path is a Linux path.  However, your VS Code is a Windows program, and it doesn't know that the path that's provided should be interpreted as a Linux (WSL) path and instead it interprets it as a Windows path.

You have a couple of options:

1. Use a Linux version of VS Code instead of a Windows version.  That will likely involve setting up an X server.
2. Use a different editor in Linux.
3. Change your editor to use a shell script that invokes VS Code with a Windows version of a path.  This will only work if VS Code can handle the special WSL paths, which not all Windows programs can, but it would look like this:

```
$ git config --global core.editor \
  'f () { printf '\''%s\0'\'' "$@" | xargs -0 -I{} wslpath -w {} | xargs -d'\''\n'\'' code --wait; };f'
```

This sets your editor to a shell function which invokes `wslpath -w` on each path and then provide each of those to VS Code on the command line.

Comment: Perhaps these links will help too : [WSL-VSCODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode) and [WSL-GIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-git)